# Spring-boot Spring-MVC application with jsp views and Swagger-ui

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-ui

We have a Spring-boot application that has jsps for view.  We are writing REST services to get the data from back-end.

Since the service needs to return a view, it is annotated with @Controller.

How can I implement it such that I can also test these services with Swagger but be able to return the view string from the REST endpoint?

Also examples mention to use @RestController, which I cannot use because of the need to return a view.

Thank you